# Why I don't see others device packets in Wireshark on same network?

Tags: wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers

I am trying to capture my iPhone's packets on MacBook that running Wireshark but I don't see any packets from iPhone but I do see packets from MacBook on my dashboard.

Both devices are connected to the same Wi-fi (which is mine). I tried both with "Monitor" options and without. I have not done any additional setups.
[image: ss]

How may I solve this? I am running latest macOS and latest Wireshark.

Thanks!

Comment: Additional setup is necessary but the documentation is out of date, https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Mac_OS_X You probably should use Windows, which is much simpler to set up.

Comment: Linux has better support for 802.11 monitoring